# How can I know sqlite database loading done in expo app

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

SQLite database is broken when executing query soon after app loading

This is Expo(react-native) app and the database is loaded from local storage.

If I wait a few seconds to use app(execute queries), the issue does not happen.

Maybe, this issue happens when a query is executed before all data loaded from local storage.

in APP.js

```
async function loadResourcesAsync() {
  await Promise.all([
 FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`, {
      intermediates: true
    }).then(
      FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        Asset.fromModule(require("./assets/db/mydb.db")).uri,
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/mydb.db`
      )
    )
  ]);
}
```

and in a Screen.js like this

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase("mydb.db");


db.transaction(
        tx => {
          tx.executeSql(sql, [queryChar], (_, { rows: { _array } }) => {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(_array));
            setSearchResult(_array);
          });
        },
        e => {
          console.log(e);
          });
        },
        null
      );
```

I expect a callback from `openDatabase` function, but it does not have such a callback.

How can I know a database loading done?

Comment: can you post your code with demo example  in expo snack?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@yosukep/sqlite-db-loading-example I put the example in expo snack.

Comment: you have compilation  errors in snack

Comment: Look at sql-lite working snack: https://snack.expo.io/@charliecruzan/sqlite-example